# Unexpected Behaviour with parsing this grammar with PEG.js

Tags: javascript, parsing, syntax, antlr, peg

I'm new to the world of formal grammars. I tried to use [ANTLR for JS](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-javascript) but couldn't figure out how to run the parser. I'm trying to develop a grammar for a DSL on [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/) and this is what I have (http://peg.arcanis.fr/3T2PKD/):

```
start 
  = expr

operator
  = "show" lparen st:string ws rparen { console.log(7)}
  / "show" lparen ex:expr rparen      { console.log(8)}

expr 
 = op: operator ws ex: expr  {console.log (1)}
 / st:string ws ex: expr     {console.log (2)}
 / st:string ws op:operator  {console.log (3)}
 / op:operator ws str:string {console.log (4)}
 / st:string ws              {console.log (5)}
 / op:operator ws            {console.log (6)}

lparen
  = ws "(" ws

rparen
  = ws ")" ws

integer "integer"
  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }

string "string"
  = quotation_mark chars:char* quotation_mark { return chars.join(""); }

ws "whitespace" = [ \t\n\r]*

char
  = unescaped
  / escape
    sequence:(
        '"'
      / "\\"
      / "/"
      / "b" { return "\b"; }
      / "f" { return "\f"; }
      / "n" { return "\n"; }
      / "r" { return "\r"; }
      / "t" { return "\t"; }
      / "u" digits:$(HEXDIG HEXDIG HEXDIG HEXDIG) {
          return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(digits, 16));
        }
    )
    { return sequence; }

escape         = "\\"
quotation_mark = '"'
unescaped      = [\x20-\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\u10FFFF]

/* ----- Core ABNF Rules ----- */

/* See RFC 4234, Appendix B (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627). */
DIGIT  = [0-9]
HEXDIG = [0-9a-f]i

{
  ;
}
```

When this is tested on: `show ("abc")` Shouldn't the console show
7
6
?

Instead it shows
7
7
7
6

Have been racking my brain for the past 3 days. Someone, somewhere help me get to ***parsimoniousness!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser has to try the rules `op: operator ws ex: expr` and `op:operator ws str:string` before it finally succeeds with `op:operator ws`. It doesn't know that those won't work until it fails to find anything beyond the `)`.

Thus, it gets through the `operator` rule once, doesn't see another expression, so it backtracks. It then sees the `operator` for the *second* time, and it *still* doesn't work because there's no string after it. So finally, on the third try, it sees the operator and then that last rule succeeds.

Your calls to `console.log(7)` are made because the `operator` rule itself succeeds, even though the `expr` rules don't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it will execute a rule **only** if it matches. I am writing some more JS code in the `{}` after the `console` calls. My logic is going haywire because I'm expecting one call. Anyway I can work around this?

Comment: @GauravRamanan well I tried a couple things, but I'm not really sure what your grammar is trying to do. Maybe you could factor out the right-sides of the rules that *start* with `operator` so that the parser doesn't have to backtrack very far?

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't quite get that, but you've explained the behavior to me pretty well! Now I am simply returning the result with a `return` statement in all rules with `operator` but storing the result in all rules with `expr`. Do you think you can perhaps *point* me to some relevant documentation where I could sharpen my skills of PEG?